# howto achieve an UIView to be displayed only in a specific area of the screen (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, translation

I have my viewcontroller.
I have my UIView in my Viewcontroller

```
@IBOutlet var myview: MyView!
```

I instanciated my myview :

```
let halfescreen=self.view.frame.height/2;
let onlyinlowerpart=CGRectMake(0, halfescreen, self.view.frame.width, halfescreen);
myview=MyView(frame: onlyinlowerpart);
myview.frame=CGRectMake(0, halfescreen, self.view.frame.width, halfescreen);
```

myview.backgroundcolor=UIColor.blueColor();

When displayed, I can see a blue screen in the lower part of the screen. Great !

When I translate the myview to move up it will go out of my specified area.

How can I fix my myview to be displayed only in the specified area. In the end I would like to move the content in this view by translating ( CGAffineTransformTranslate() ) the view and scaling, but all should be in that specified frame of the screen.

Does someone has a hint how to do/structure this ? Is there any ViewContainer to be specified ?

**UPDATE** 
Izaak Prats, thanks for helping and bringing me on the right path, but I still do not succeed. Can you help again ? I added the constraint (top) with following code, but still when CGAffineTransformTranslate it goes over the top constraint.

```
view.addSubview(myview);


            // Set constraints for the worldmap
            let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal,toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: halfescreen)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([pinTop])
```

Comment: Are you using a scrollView? I think putting this view as a subview to a scrollView's content View would solve your problem. Where out of your specified area is your myview going to?

Comment: Thanks for helping. No it is not in a scrollview. I would like to do the scrolling by myself by translating the view. I am drawing a worldmap, which should not displayed over the entire screen. It should be only visible in a specific area.

Comment: with your updated code you are essentially saying i want the top constraint to be equal to top constraint plus half the screens distance, try setting your constant to 0 if you just want it to equal the top constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to be setting your frame twice. The last line of code is redundant.

To get the view where you want it to be, you can **programmatically set constraints** onto views.

Here is Apple's documentation - [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I guess this is the right way to do. But practically I do not succeed in doing this. Could you probably help me out with the updated code in my question ?